# getting all values from array with 'list' and #foreach'

Tags: php, arrays, list, foreach

i try to list a overview for a gallary by using 'list' and 'foreach' , but i always get just one (the oldest) result from my database.

i use this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 

           $galpath1 = "galerie/";
           $gal_title = $row['gal_title'];
           $gal_path= $galpath1.$row['uploads'];
           $nickname = $row['nickname'];
           $added = $row['format_date']; 



            $galshow = [
                        [$gal_path, $gal_title, $added],
                     ]; 
            }
if(!empty($gal_path))    
{

 var_dump($galshow);
foreach ($galshow as list($gal_pathes, $gal_titles,  $addeds)) {
List of galerys
}
```

how can i bring it to work so that i can list all gallerys that matches the select in my database?

**Thank you so much cdhowie**
you saved my day. that was exactly what i did wrong. 
so thanks for the quick response. :)

Answer (score 1):

Every iteration of the `while` loop you *overwrite* the value in `$galshow` with a new array containing one element.  As a result, this array will only ever contain one element, and it will be the last row fetched from the database.

Instead, create a new array outside of the loop and append to it inside the loop:

```
$galshow = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $galpath1 = "galerie/";
    $gal_title = $row['gal_title'];
    $gal_path = $galpath1.$row['uploads'];
    $nickname = $row['nickname'];
    $added = $row['format_date']; 

    // This syntax will append a new array to the end of the $galshow array.
    $galshow[] = [$gal_path, $gal_title, $added];
}
```